# JPA very strange error when change query parameter

Tags: java, sql, jpa, persistence, dml

I'm having an strange issue in this query.
Code:

```
em2=getNewEntityManager();
(...)
Query query2 = em2.createNativeQuery("SELECT DISTINCT ID_ZONA FROM VWG_REL_USUARIOS_ZONAS WHERE DNI like '"+dni+"'") ;
                List <Long> permisos = query2.getResultList();
(...)
```

If "dni" equals to: "%" the query goes normal, but if "dni" is "%123456789" gives this error

> javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002]
>   (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b):
>   org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
>           Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: sql string is not a dml statement
>           Error Code: 17129
>           Call: SELECT DISTINCT ID_ZONA FROM VWG_REL_USUARIOS_ZONAS WHERE DNI like '%XX828747B'
>           Query: DataReadQuery(sql="SELECT DISTINCT ID_ZONA FROM VWG_REL_USUARIOS_ZONAS WHERE DNI like '%XX828747B'")

And if I copy the exact query above in my SQL developer, it works as magic.
I've tried with the "createQuery" with the entities and all the stuff, same error.

Thanks a lot

Comment: dni is an integer or string type?

Comment: String type, spanish DNI format

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning the value to a parameter, such as:

```
String dni = "some value";
Query query2 = em2.createNativeQuery("SELECT DISTINCT ID_ZONA FROM VWG_REL_USUARIOS_ZONAS WHERE DNI like :param") ;
query2.setParamter("param", dni);
List <Long> permisos = query2.getResultList();
```

Update: In EclipseLink, Only indexed parameters are supported, named parameters are not supported.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I'm affraid it gives me the same error, in same cases. :(

Comment: @LuayAbdulraheem Named parameters in native queries are not portable (and unsupported in EclipseLink)

Comment: @crizzis Thanks for pointing that. Only indexed parameters are supported in EclipseLink, so try that instead of named parameters. For help: https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/Native

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it, it is working now.

I was changing DNI value in debugging mode in eclipse, to fit the test I want to do. So a session validator invalidated my the user as some of the data "by magic" changed in an strange way. To do the test without compiling every time, I have to change DNI value BEFORE session is created.

What I don't know is why is it giving so specific SQL exception when the error originated validating the session. Something like "session is invalid" would have saved me a couple of hours...

Thanks all for your time